# C++ vector is declared 1D but accessed in a 2D way

Tags: c++, arrays

I found some C++ code on the internet and I had a problem trying to understand it. So I have an array of Strings called `vetor` with 105 positions. After the declaration there's an if statement that tries to access the array like a matrix. How is that possible?

```
string vetor[105];

for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    bool ok = true;
    for(int i = 0, i < (int((text).size()))-(int((vetor[k]).size()))+1; ++i) {
        ok = true;
        for(int j = 0, j < (int((vetor[k]).size())); ++j) {
            if(text[i+j] != vetor[k][j]) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ok) {
            res.push_back(ii(i, i-1+(int((vetor[k]).size()))));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: std::string has an indexing operator on its own

Comment: String are arrays themselves, therefore you have a 2D array. You access the string with `vetor[k]` and access a singular character of the string with `vetor[k][j]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So it would be the character k of the string in the position j or the opposite?

Comment: There's no vector here, just an array of strings.

Comment: It's the character j of string k

Comment: Read it from left to right: `vetor[k]` is the k'th  element of `vetor`, and `[j]` is the j'th character of that.